# Confused about considering j=0 in Stochastic process exercises

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This is one of my questions in Stochastic Process: A store that stocks a certain commodity uses the following $(s, S)$ ordering policy; if its supply at the beginning of a time period is $x$, then it orders
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \quad x \geq s \\
S-x \quad x<s
\end{array}\right.
$$
The order is immediately filled. The daily demands are independent and equal $j$ with probability $\alpha_j$. All demands that cannot be immediately met are lost. Let $X_n$ denote the inventory level at the end of the nth time period. Argue that $\left\{X_n, n \geq 1\right\}$ is a Markov chain and compute its transition probabilities.
This is a very simple question i thought. And i think the answer is(which is from http://www.charmpeach.com/category/stochastic-processes/page/2/):

Let $Y_i$ denote the demand of the ith day, then
$$
X_n= \begin{cases}X_{n-1}-Y_n & X_{n-1} \geq s \\ S-Y_n & X_{n-1}<s\end{cases}
$$
Since $Y_i$ is independent, $\left\{X_n, n \geq 1\right\}$ is a Markov chain, and its transition probabilities are
$$
P_{i j}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\alpha_{i-j} \quad i \geq s, i \geq j \\
\alpha_{S-j} \quad i<s \\
\end{array}\right.
$$

However, i see another solution considers $j=0$ situation which makes me very confused:

Denote by $O_n$ the amount of order and $D_n$ the amount of demand at the beginning of period $n$. We have
$$
X_{n+1}=\left(X_n+O_n-D_n\right)^{+}
$$
where
$$
X_n+O_n= \begin{cases}S & X_n<s \\ X_n & X_n \geq s\end{cases}
$$
and $D_n$ is independent to the history $\left(X_n, X_{n-1}, \ldots\right)$. So $\left(X_n\right)$ is a Markov chain.
$$
P_{i, j}=\operatorname{Pr}\left(X_{n+1}=j \mid X_n=i\right)=\operatorname{Pr}\left(\left(i+O_n-D_n\right)^{+}=j\right)
$$
If $j=0$, we have
$$
P_{i, j}=\operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n \geq i+O_n\right)= \begin{cases}\operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n \geq S\right)=\sum_{k=S}^{\infty} \alpha_k & i<s \\ \operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n \geq i\right)=\sum_{k=i}^{\infty} \alpha_k & i \geq s\end{cases}
$$
If $j>0$, we have
$$
P_{i, j}=\operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n=i+O_n-j\right)= \begin{cases}\operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n=S-j\right)=\alpha_{S-j} & i<s \\ \operatorname{Pr}\left(D_n=i-j\right)=\alpha_{i-j} & i \geq s\end{cases}
$$

I don't make sense why we need to consider $j=0$ and why the answer is not same as above. Which solution is correct? I would be very appreciate if you can give me any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution does not take into account the sentence

> All demands that cannot be immediately met are lost.

which corresponds to the intuitive constraint that the stock cannot become negative. So the correct expression for $X_n$ is:
$$X_n = \begin{cases}X_{n - 1} - Y_n & \text{if } X_{n-1} \ge s \text{ and } 
X_{n - 1} > Y_n\\
S - Y_n & \text{if } X_{n - 1} < s \text{ and } S > Y_n \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
You should be able to deduce that $X_n$ is a Markov process and the correct transition probabilities from here.

Comment: Make sense. So the TPM didn't have the $P_{i0}$ column?

Comment: It's more that it should not have entries for $i < 0$ or $j < 0$ (or you could think of all those entries being $0$).